# Generate missing rows in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking for an elegant solution to generate some missing integers in SQL.

An example would be:

| rn | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dim1 | 100 |
| 2 | dim1 | 150 |
| 3 | dim1 | 200 |
| 4 | dim1 | 150 |
| 5 | dim1 | 100 |
| 6 | dim1 | 50 |
| 7 | dim1 | 0 |
| 1 | dim2 | 600 |
| 2 | dim2 | 700 |
| 3 | dim2 | 500 |

from there, I would like to UNION the following:

| rn | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | dim2 | 0 |
| 5 | dim2 | 0 |
| 6 | dim2 | 0 |
| 7 | dim2 | 0 |

Question being, how best to genrate the second table?
Assume maximum value for rn is the same for dim1, dim2, and any other dims.

Comment: How is the code supposed to know the max RN for dim2? What happens if dim2 already has a higher RN than dim1?

Comment: Assume max for dim1 is the same as max for dim2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join all your combinations of rns and names with your original table, then use `COALESCE` to fill missing values with 0. This will avoid you the `UNION` and doesn't need to know in advance what's the max amount of values for each name.

```
WITH combinations AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT rn   FROM tab) rns
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tab) names 
)
SELECT c.*, COALESCE(tab.value_, 0) AS value_
FROM      combinations c
LEFT JOIN tab
       ON c.rn = tab.rn AND c.name = tab.name
ORDER BY name, rn
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DdOeaVRm).

Comment: Yes! Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
    rn INT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    value INT
);


INSERT INTO example_table (rn, name, value) VALUES (1, 'dim1', 100);
INSERT INTO example_table (rn, name, value) VALUES (2, 'dim1', 150);
INSERT INTO example_table (rn, name, value) VALUES (3, 'dim1', 200);
INSERT INTO example_table (rn, name, value) VALUES (4, 'dim1', 150);
INSERT INTO example_table (rn, name, value) VALUES (5, 'dim1', 100);
INSERT INTO example_table (rn, name, value) VALUES (6, 'dim1', 50);
INSERT INTO example_table (rn, name, value) VALUES (7, 'dim1', 0);
INSERT INTO example_table (rn, name, value) VALUES (1, 'dim2', 600);
INSERT INTO example_table (rn, name, value) VALUES (2, 'dim2', 700);
INSERT INTO example_table (rn, name, value) VALUES (3, 'dim2', 500);


DECLARE @MaxValues INT

SELECT @MaxValues = MAX(rn)
FROM example_table;


SELECT Names.name   
      ,DS.row_id
      ,ISNULL(ET.value, 0) AS [value]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT name  
    FROM example_table
) Names
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (@MaxValues) row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
    FROM master..spt_values t1 
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
) DS(row_id)
LEFT JOIN example_table ET
    ON Names.name = ET.name
    AND DS.row_id = ET.rn
ORDER BY Names.name, DS.row_id
```

[image]

It should work with more complex data.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (rn int, name varchar(10), value int)

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(1, 'dim1', 100),
(2, 'dim1', 150),
(3, 'dim1', 200),
(4, 'dim1', 150),
(5, 'dim1', 100),
(6, 'dim1', 50),
(7, 'dim1', 0),
(1, 'dim2', 600),
(2, 'dim2', 700),
(3, 'dim2', 500)
```

You could join the table with itself to get all dims/names and join again with itself to get missing rn values for each name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT base.rn, dims.name, 0 
FROM t1 AS base
INNER JOIN t1 AS dims ON base.name<>dims.name
LEFT JOIN t1 AS missing ON base.rn=missing.rn AND missing.name=dims.name
WHERE missing.rn IS NULL
ORDER BY 2,1
```

This would also assure that every dim has every nr: As soon as a nr is specified in any dim, this query will return the nr for every other dim in the table.